# Adding new row in a CSV Python

Tags: python, csv

I am adding a new row to a specific CSV that already exist, but for unknown reason the new row is being added along with the last row and not in a new one.

So, it's showing in CSV as:

```
11-07-2016,38361,9076,14487,292,741614-07-2016,38417,9767,15832,301,7416
```

When should be showing as:

```
11-07-2016,38361,9076,14487,292,7416
14-07-2016,38417,9767,15832,301,7416
```

My code is:

```
import time
import csv


today = (time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
newRow = """%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s""" % (today, yes, ok, war, leg, noag)
fd = open('data.csv','a')
fd.write(newRow)
fd.close()
```

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the file doesn't have a newline at the end. Try adding one before appending the new line:

```
newRow = "\n%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % (today, yes, ok, war, leg, noag)
with open("data.csv", "a") as f:
    f.write(newRow)
```

Comment: You solved his specific problem, but did this help him understand what went wrong?

Comment: actually I think I understood, adding the\n it forced the newRow to be in a new row, right? Thank you.

Comment: @Gonzalo that's right if you use the file as a text file. But if you want to use it as a csv file with the csv module you don't need to add the `\n` manualy.

Comment: but now the file has a empty row between each line.. it happens everytime   i run the code.. so somehing must be wrong.

Comment: @Gonzalo that because you add `\n` at the beginning and at the end of the newRow.

Comment: @Gonzalo you just need to add newline = ''. You can see my answer for reference

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import csv


today = (time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
newRow = """%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s""" % (today, yes, ok, war, leg, noag)
with open('data.csv','a',newline='') as fd:
    writer = csv.writer(fd)
    writer.writerow(newRow)
```

It's writerow instead of write, it'll automatically add a new line. and newline = '' prevents your skip a line.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are not using the csv module, just the regular write as for text file.

To treat the file as a csv change:

```
fd.write(newRow)
```

to:

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(fd)
csv_writer.writerow(newRow)
```

If you want to edit the file as a text file you should add the "new line charecter" manualy, so:

```
fd.write('\n' + newRow)
```

will work (in that case the `import csv` is redundant)